# android client id create linked app

Tags: android, linked-list, client

I have been struggling with setting up my app in the Android Developer Console. Specifically, I need to set up and assign a client ID to the App (or linked app, not sure), however, I am unable to do so.

Any attempt to create the client ID I am told one already exists. Yet, I can not publish my app since the app is not linked to one with a client ID.. or so I gather.

//I am unable to press the create button. I am blocked out from doing so. 
[image]

///the step required to publish.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the correct package name that your app uses as well as generate the fingerprint using key gen and paste that key there. Without those, you cannot create a client id for your app. The required steps are explained in great detail in their help pages.